# Relative directories don't seem to work with filesets in maven assembly descriptors. Any way to do this?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

According to the maven assembly plugin docs, relative directories are allowed, but ".." doesn't seem to work at all.

For reasons I cannot go into (and I cannot change), there are some files outside of the maven project directory I want to include in the assembly.

```
/-
---maven-project/
---some-crap/
```

I have tried various things:

```
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/../some-crap</directory>
        <outputDirectory>crapdir</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileset>
```

or

```
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
        <outputDirectory>crapdir</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>../some-crap/**/*</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileset>
```

or

```
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>../some-crap</directory>
        <outputDirectory>crapdir</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileset>
```

etc.
My maven version is 3.0.4 (latest)

Outside of writing something in ant to fetch this stuff or copying it to my target dir before assembling, is there anything I can do?

I really think the assembly plugin is treating ".." as a directory name and not "go up one level".

Thanks.

Comment: try ${project.basedir}/../../some-crap

Comment: <directory>${project.basedir}/../..</directory> just resolves to ${project.basedir}, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using maven-antrun-plugin to copy files to your project dir before assembling?

```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>prepare-deploy-package</id>
                   <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>run</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <tasks>
                           <copy todir="${project.build.directory}">
                               <fileset dir="../xxxx">
                               </fileset>
                           </copy>
                       </tasks>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
```